# Errors when using | instead of typing.Union in dataclasses type hints

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.11

I am using Python 3.11.3 on Linux and currently for my union types in dataclasses I am using the following type hints:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Union

import numpy as np


@dataclass
class Test:
    data: Union[np.array, list[tuple]]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Test(data=np.array([2, 1]))
    test2 = Test(data=[(1, 2), (1, 2)])
```

Now I read, that we can replace the `Union[]`  syntax with the more elegant `|` syntax since 3.10 but this does not work for me.

For example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

import numpy as np


@dataclass
class Test:
    data: np.array | list[tuple]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Test(data=np.array([2, 1]))
    test2 = Test(data=[(1, 2), (1, 2)])
```

throws the following error:

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/test/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Test:
  File "/home/user/test/test.py", line 8, in Test
    data: np.array | list[tuple]
          ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'types.GenericAlias'
```

Do I miss something? Or does this not work for data classes?

Comment: `np.array` is not a type.

Comment: What happens if you use `np.ndarray` instead; as this *is* a type.

Comment: The return type of `np.array` is `numpy.typing.ArrayLike` (a union which, I believe, also includes `list` already).

Comment: thanks for the tip. I guess the problem was the `np.array`, with `np.ndarray` it works.